# Move an array element of a sorted array to another position with special logic

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, logic

I have an sorted collection like this:

```
 var sortedCollection = [
     {id: 3,x: 1,y: 1},
     {id: 2,x: 1,y: 2},
     {id: 1,x: 2,y: 1},
     {id: 9,x: 2,y: 2},
     {id: 5,x: 2,y: 3},
     {id: 8,x: 2,y: 4},
     {id: 7,x: 3,y: 1},
     {id: 6,x: 3,y: 2},
     {id: 4,x: 4,y: 1}
 ];
```

The collection is sorted by x first and y as second sort value.

The x and y values in my collection represent a matrix view. With the example model it looks like this:

```
[][][][]
[][][]
  []
  []
```

Similar structure reveal.js presentations use, if this is easier to understand.

It is possible to drag and drop the elements ( [] represents one element ).
If I drop an element to another I show an indicator where the dragged element is placed (above, below, before, after). The data in the colllection is needed to resort the elements (which are thumbnails) and send it back to the server

The functionality of moving one item should following this logic:
I pick one item, e.g. `{x: 2,y: 2}`, which I want to move within the collection. A second item is the reference for placing this element, e.g. `{x: 3, y: 2}` . It should be possible to place the element above, below, before and after this element.

This means for my two example values `{x: 2,y: 2}` and `{x: 3, y: 2}` as referencing the placement + the information below:

- "above" means `{x: 2,y: 2}` becomes `{x: 3, y: 2}` and all values after that and the duplicate value `{x: 3, y: 2}` with the same x value iterate by one
- "below" means `{x: 2,y: 2}` becomes `{x: 3, y: 3}` and all values after that with the same x value iterate by one

Before and After operations only work with values which have y: 1 (example  `{x: 2,y: 2}` and `{x: 3, y: 1}`)

- "before" means `{x: 2,y: 2}` becomes `{x: 3, y: 1}` and the `{x: 3, y: 1}` becomes `{x: 4, y: 1}` and all other object which has an x-value of 3 become 4 all elements x-value is iterated by one
- "after" means `{x: 2,y: 2}` becomes `{x: 4, y: 1}` and the `{x: 3, y: 1}` stays the same but all elements which have an x-value greater then 4 must iterate by one

I hope I made no mistake in describing what I need. I can't manage it to handle every case of filling gaps or handling duplicates for fixing the numeric series within the collection.
Any hint on programming this in JavaScript or on simplifying this logic would be helpful.

I created a JSFiddle which shows the main idea, with a todo comment on the position where I get stuck:
http://jsfiddle.net/FrontEnds/69PXk/8/

Comment: How far did you get? Have a jsfiddle with your findings so far?
How about simply pushing the element and sorting the list again?

Comment: @Ela pushing the object and sorting the list again wouldn't modify the objects after the pushed one.

Comment: What is it that x and y represent?  Maybe the problem is with the current solution?  A linked list sounds like it would be more practical if you are updating the internal values of each object as well as moving them.  The problem I see with your model, is constantly moving two objects one after the other, will result in infinitely increasing 'x' values.

Comment: I updated my description to make the goal a bit clearer.

Comment: @HenriPodolski I don't get it, is there a `{x:2,y:5}` in the grid you updated ?

Comment: Yes it's possible to have that, if you take {x:2,y:4} as reference point and set it to place it below. If you place it before {x: 3, y: 1} it becomes {x: 3, y: 1} and every following elements gets 1 added to its x value. So {x: 3, y: 1} becomes {x: 4, y: 1}. Given that you take an item with more than one item with the same x-value. If you take one item witch is the only one with that x-value it leaves a gap, which must be closed in the numerical sequence.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle which shows the main idea, with a todo comment on the position where I get stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/FrontEnds/69PXk/8/

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 ok, now I know what you mean. In the second column were too much items. I fixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution that seems to work:

```
var sortedCollection = [
     {id: 3,x: 1,y: 1},
     {id: 2,x: 1,y: 2},
     {id: 1,x: 2,y: 1},
     {id: 9,x: 2,y: 2},
     {id: 5,x: 2,y: 3},
     {id: 8,x: 2,y: 4},
     {id: 7,x: 3,y: 1},
     {id: 6,x: 3,y: 2},
     {id: 4,x: 4,y: 1}
 ];

// example case
var  movedItemIndex = 3 // change this value to which item you want to move
    ,movedItem = sortedCollection[movedItemIndex]
    ,movedItemId = movedItem.id
    ,referenceItemIndex = 6 // change this value to which item reference where you want to move your item
    ,referenceItem = sortedCollection[referenceItemIndex]
    ,referenceItemId = referenceItem.id
    ,relativePlacing = "above"; // second reference indicator one of (above, below, before, after)

sortedCollection = moveSortedCollectionItem( sortedCollection, movedItemIndex, referenceItem.x, referenceItem.y, relativePlacing );
sortedCollection = fixSortCollectionsNumericalXAndYSequence( sortedCollection, movedItemId, referenceItemId );
console.dir( sortedCollection );

function moveSortedCollectionItem( sortedCollection, itemIndex, refPosX, refPosY, relativePlace )
{    
    switch( true )
    {
        case( relativePlace == "above" || relativePlace == "before" ):
            {
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].x = refPosX
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].y = refPosY
                break;
            }

        case( relativePlace == "below" ):
            {
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].x = refPosX
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].y = refPosY + 1
                break;
            }           

        case( relativePlace == "after" ):
            {
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].x = refPosX + 1
                sortedCollection[itemIndex].y = refPosY
                break;
            }
    }

    return sortedCollection;
}

function fixSortCollectionsNumericalXAndYSequence( sortedCollection, movedItemId, referenceItemId )
{    
    // make sure we have the right sort order
    sortedCollection.sort( sortByXAndY );

    // return sortedCollection;

    for( var i = 0, len = sortedCollection.length; i < len; i++ )
    {
        if( i == 0 && (sortedCollection[i].x != 1 || sortedCollection[i].y != 1) )
        {
            // first one must have x: 1 and y; 1 in order to make the whole thing work
            sortedCollection[i].x = 1;
            sortedCollection[i].y = 1;
        }
        else if( typeof sortedCollection[i-1] != 'undefined' /* has previous item */ )
        {
            sortedCollection[i] = _replaceXAndYFromItemWithPreviousItem( sortedCollection[i-1], sortedCollection[i] );
        }
    }

    return sortedCollection;
}

function _replaceXAndYFromItemWithPreviousItem( previousItem, currentItem )
{    
    // case: previous item x and current item x are the same
    if( currentItem.x == previousItem.x )
    {
        // set current item y = previous item y + 1
        currentItem.y = previousItem.y + 1;
    }  
    // case: current item x is not previous item x and not previous item x + 1
    else if( currentItem.x != previousItem.x && currentItem.x != previousItem.x + 1 )
    {
        // set current item x = previous item x + 1; set current item y = 1
        currentItem.x = previousItem.x + 1;                
        currentItem.y = 1;
    }

    return currentItem;
}

function sortByXAndY( model1, model2 )
{
    var  a = parseInt( model1.x )
        ,b = parseInt( model2.x )

    if( a == b )
    {
        var  c = parseInt( model1.y )
            ,d = parseInt( model2.y );

        return c - d;
    }

    return a - b;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69PXk/17/